# \sum not properly displayed?

Tags: math-operators

When I do `$ \sum_{k=1}^{K} $` I get this:

[image]

But I want to get this:

[image]

where `i` is above!

I am working in `beamer`.

Comment: Add `\displaystyle` to the beginning, since you must have invoked it with a `$` or a `\(`.  As in `$\dislaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{K}$`.  Alternately, you can invoke it with `\[\sum_{k=1}^{K}\]` which will put it in display style on a line by itself.

Comment: You are right I am using `$ ... $` to display Math equations ... do I have to add `\displaystyle` before `begin{document}` ? what `\displaystyle` does ?

Comment: I updated my comment to address my ambiguity.

Comment: excellent, It is working, can you please explain to me the difference between : `$ ... $` and `\[ ... \]` ? or show me a reference article for help ?

Comment: If it's in an inline formula, type `$\sum\limits_{k=1}^K$`

Comment: `$...$` (which is functionally equivalent with `\(...\)`) places the math in "inline" text style, for times when you want to include the math as part of a sentence.  `\[...\]` places math on a separate line in a less compacted display style.  If you need the displaystyle equation numbered, you should use something like the `equation` environment.

Comment: excellent, now I make the difference between `$..$`, `\[ ... \]` and `equation` environment. Suppose that I am using the `equation` environment , How do I put a reference to an equation ?

Comment: If you want your comment directed at a specific person you have to put their name lead by and `@` in your comment, such as  @ALJIMohamed.  Otherwise, it goes to the owner of the post (in this case you).  To answer your follow up, you want to use `\label{labelname}` inside the equation environment and `\ref{labelname}` at other points in your document.  It would behoove you to use this site's search feature for these things, as many of these answers will already cover your particular questions.